# Does "Exception" catches the exception even if that exception was specifically mentioned in the catch blocks?

Tags: java, exception

```
catch(TimeoutException e)
    {
        //something here
    }
catch(SomeOtherException e)
    {
        //something here
    }
catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        //something here
    }
catch(Exception excep)
    {
        //something here
    }
```

My question is, if there is a NullPointerException, it will be caught by the nullpointerexception catch block. Will it also be caught by exception catch block? Can I use excep variable to get the type of exception ?

Comment: Did you try it ;)

Comment: 30 seconds. That's all it takes to try it out *and* get yourself a nice drink from the fridge.

Comment: I didnt, and I am sorry for that but I am in a hurry.

Comment: @bhatianitish That's not a good use of StackOverflow, get back to this issue when you're not in a hurry, don't rush your code ;)

Comment: It takes more time to post a question..

Answer (score 3):

No, because above the `catch (Exception excep)` block you have a block to specifically catch `NullPointerException`.

An exception is never caught by multiple catch blocks*.

If you remove the `catch (NullPointerException e)` block, then the `catch (Exception excep)` block *will* also catch `NullPointerException` (because `NullPointerException` is a subclass of `Exception`). And in that case, you could use the `excep` variable to check the type of exception. That would, however, be bad practice - it's better to add a catch block for the specific exception type, instead of testing the type of the exception variable.

*: Unless, in the `catch (NullPointerException e)` block, you re-throw the exception, as Juan Mendes mentions in his comment.

Comment: Unless you re-throw it?

Comment: So, if I have to store the type of exception in a string, I have to write same code like - "String exceptionName = blahblah" in every catch block?

Comment: @bhatianitish why would you need to do that? the whole point of being able to catch a specific type of exception is that you _know_ what type it is ahead of time.

Comment: If you're going to handle all exceptions in the exact same way, it doesn't make a lot of sense to copy and paste the same catch block 4 times... You could use multi-catch: `catch (TimeoutException | SomeOtherException e)`